# Simultaneously highlight two associated words on hover (HTML, JS, PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a little help.

I want to be able to simultaneously highlight two (or more) different but related words on a page when I hover over or click *either* of them.

This is the kind of thing I mean:

[Example of parallel French-English text with highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvt5c.png)

In the example, if I hover over 'croyez' in French then the word English word 'believe' is highlighted and *vice versa*. I would want to create correspondences for every word in the text.

I came across this code, which I edited a bit. It does the job but is obviously inelegant and would be too laborious to create links for a large file.

```
JAVASCRIPT:
var spana = document.getElementsByClassName('classA');
var i = 0;
while(i < spana.length){
    spana[i].onmouseover = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < spana.length){
            spana[i].style.color = 'red';
            i++;
        }
    }

    spana[i].onmouseout = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < spana.length){
            spana[i].style.color = 'black';
            i++;
        }
    }

    i++;
}

var spanb = document.getElementsByClassName('classB');
var i = 0;
while(i < spanb.length){
    spanb[i].onmouseover = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < spanb.length){
            spanb[i].style.color = 'red';
            i++;
        }
    }

    spanb[i].onmouseout = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < spanb.length){
            spanb[i].style.color = 'black';
            i++;
        }
    }

    i++;
}

var spanc = document.getElementsByClassName('classC');
var i = 0;
while(i < spanc.length){
    spanc[i].onmouseover = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < spanc.length){
            spanc[i].style.color = 'red';
            i++;
        }
    }

    spanc[i].onmouseout = function change(){
        var i = 0;
        while(i < spanc.length){
            spanc[i].style.color = 'black';
            i++;
        }
    }

    i++;
}

CSS:
.classA:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.classB:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.classB:hover {
  color: blue;
}

HTML:
<div class="wrapper_class">
<span class="classA">Le</span>
<span class="classB">chat</span>
<span class="classC">noir</span>
<span class="classA">The</span>
<span class="classC">black</span>
<span class="classB">cat</span>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help,
AB

Comment: You question is too broad. You should add some code to your question.

Comment: I've added some code now - thanks

Comment: The corresponding words highlight each other with this code. Eg, if you hover over noir, both noir and black highlight. And if you hover over block, both black and noir highlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made three changes in your code: 1. You were using the same variable `i` for two nested loops. So, I named the second variable as `j`. 2: I switched the position of the HTML and the JavaScript code as the JavaScript code was referring to the HTML tags which were written after the JavaScript code. 3: I have reduced the JavaScript code, as requested by you.

```
<div class="wrapper_class">
<span class="classA">Le</span>
<span class="classB">chat</span>
<span class="classC">noir</span>
<span class="classA">The</span>
<span class="classC">black</span>
<span class="classB">cat</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$chars = ['A','B','C'];
for($i=0;$i<count($chars);$i++){
?>
var span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?> = document.getElementsByClassName('class<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>');
var i = 0;
while(i < span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>.length){
    span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>[i].onmouseover = function change(){
        var j = 0;
        while(j < span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>.length){
            span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>[j].style.color = 'red';
            j++;
        }
    }

    span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>[i].onmouseout = function change(){
        var j = 0;
        while(j < span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>.length){
            span<?php echo $chars[$i]; ?>[j].style.color = 'black';
            j++;
        }
    }

    i++;
}
<?php } ?>
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.classA:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.classB:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.classB:hover {
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to write it so you don't need to repeat the

var spana = document.getElementsByClassName('classA');
var i = 0; ...

section of code each time a new link between words is needed (e.g. spanb, spanc, spand...)?

Comment: It can be achieved using a PHP loop. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help!